# What order do the MGS games take place chronologically?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-series

So we've established that MGSV: TPP comes before MGS2, but what about the other games in the MGS franchise, including MGR:R?

What order do the MGS games take place chronologically?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### The order of the Metal Gear Solid Series timeline is as follows:

1. 1964: Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Eater
2. 1970: Metal Gear Solid: Portable Ops
3. 1974: Metal Gear Solid: Peace Walker
4. 1975: Metal Gear Solid: Ground Zeroes
5. 1984: Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain
6. 1995: Metal Gear
7. 1999: Metal Gear 2: Solid Snake
8. 2005: Metal Gear Solid
9. 2007 - 2009: Metal Gear Solid 2: Sons of Liberty
10. 2014: Metal Gear Solid 4: Guns of the Patriots
11. 2016 - 2018: Metal Gear Rising: Revengance

Comment: Extra note: As a personal recommendation from a fellow fan of the franchise, do yourself a favor and **play the games in release order** regardless of the actual chronology of the universe, assuming that THE OP might be asking this because they want to play the games in the order of the in-universe timeline. The games are designed to be played in the order that they were released (most notably, Kojima thought he was making the last MGS game every time in the main iterations), and the plot, although somewhat disjointed, will make more sense digested that way.

Comment: Also worth noting that kojima has stated that metal gear rising is not Canon in the metal gear universe
https://youtu.be/n6OGvhlKNzw